# Как получить текст с атрибута "a" , сравнивая тем что находится внутри "strong" при парсинге c помощью htmlagilitypack

Tags: c#, htmlagilitypack

Прошу прощения за заголовок, не знал как написать.
Есть **div** блок который содержит в себе несколько **li**. В каждом **li** написан год книги, автор, правообладатель и т.д.. Я хотел получить только правообладателя. Я думал чтобы это сделать мне нужно найти где написано `<strong> Правообладатель:</strong>` который находится в **li** и достать текст с **a** (Азбука-Аттикус). Я перепробовал много разных способов и ни один не сработал.

```html
<div class="blocks">
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
<li>
<strong>Правообладатель:</strong>
<a href="/azbuka-attikus/">Азбука-Аттикус</a>
</li>
<li>...</li>
</div>
```

Пытался я вот так:

```cs
HtmlNode pravo = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//li/strong[@text='Правообладатель:']/a");
```

Я знаю что таким образом я ни как не смогу достать текст из **a**, но у меня уже не осталось ни каких идей, как можно это сделать.

Comment: @UModeL Да, С#. Добавил

Comment: @aepot Пишет ошибку: System.NullReferenceException: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

pravo было null.

Comment: `a` - это _элемент_, а не _атрибут_! Так же как `div`, `li`, `strong`. В показанном вами html есть атрибуты `class` и `href`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хорошая шпаргалка - [Xpath cheatsheet](https://devhints.io/xpath)

> Ошибка пропала, но он берет не с того места и пишет "Икабог Дж. К. Роулинг Оглавление", а должно быть "Икабог Дж. К. Роулинг Азбука-Аттикус". Он берет данные вот оттсюда https://litres.ru/dzhoan-ketlin-rouling/ikabog

Ваша проблема в том, что вы взяли код из инспектора, то есть уже обработанный яваскриптом, встроенным в страницу, а надо брать именно исходный код страницы (правый клик по странице - Исходный код), нужная часть которого выглядит вот так:

```html
<li><strong>Правообладатель:</strong> <span data-link="/azbuka-attikus/" class="biblio_info_detailed__link biblio_book_link_js">Азбука-Аттикус</span></li>
```

Следовательно полный код получения нужной ссылки будет выглядеть вот так.

```cs
private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    string html = await client.GetStringAsync("https://www.litres.ru/dzhoan-ketlin-rouling/ikabog/");
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(html);
    HtmlNode pravo = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//strong[contains(text(),'Правообладатель')]/following::span");
    Console.WriteLine(pravo.InnerText);
    Console.WriteLine(pravo.Attributes["data-link"].Value);
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
Азбука-Аттикус
/azbuka-attikus/
```

Или даже можно проще запрос сделать

```cs
HtmlNode pravo = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[contains(@class,'biblio_book_link_js')]");
```

---

А еще можно использовать не XPath,  а CSS селектор, для этого нужно дополнительно установить NuGet пакет `Fizzler.Systems.HtmlAgilityPack`, и можно будет сделать то же самое вот так:

```cs
HtmlNode pravo = doc.DocumentNode.QuerySelector(".biblio_book_link_js");
```

Comment: `//li` лишний, достаточной найти нужный `strong`, а если нужна "точность", то лучше заменить на поиск по классу. `text()=` лучше заворачивать в `contains` (более надежней). `a[1]` - индекс лишний. Ну и `following-sibling` можно заменить просто на `following`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Ошибка пропала, но он берет не с того места и пишет "Икабог   Дж. К. Роулинг  Оглавление", а должно быть "Икабог   Дж. К. Роулинг  Азбука-Аттикус". Он берет данные вот оттсюда https://www.litres.ru/dzhoan-ketlin-rouling/ikabog/

Comment: @ils2 Зайдите [сюда](http://xpather.com/), вставьте HTML из вашего вопроса и XPath из этого ответа и гляньте на результат. С теми данными, что у нас есть, все выдало как надо, а это значит, что у вас есть нечто другое, что мешает работе. Как я говорил в первом комментарии здесь, под ответом, "если нужна точность, то лучше заменить на поиск по классу".

Comment: Выдал вот так 1.Азбука-Аттикус
2.Оглавление. На сайте все правильно работает, значит ошибка у меня в коде. Завтра разберусь. Спасибо!

Comment: @ils2 вы точно проверяете тот запрос который сейчас в ответе, потому что он редактировался. Перепроверьте.

Comment: @aepot Да, на сайте все правильно работает, значит ошибка у меня в коде. Завтра разберусь. Спасибо!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ первый блин у меня комом с XPath :) пойду дальше на CSS селекторах сидеть :)

Comment: @aepot Здесь все нормально, это решение той задачи, что в ответе. Проблема в том, что автор вопроса копирует HTML из браузера, а не из программы. Программный HTML выглядит [так](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnvGo.png), ну и тут думаю сразу становиться ясно в чем проблема (`a` меняем на `span`, а `href` на `data-link`)...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ а можете мне `li` ноду текстом или в ответ закинуть? А то с картинки лень перепечатывать:) а мобильный FF не умеет исходный код показвать. Я тогда поправлю ответ с объяснением.

Comment: [весь кусок](https://pastebin.com/jmMmnjYf), отдельно нода: `<li><strong>Правообладатель:</strong> <span data-link="/azbuka-attikus/" class="biblio_info_detailed__link biblio_book_link_js">Азбука-Аттикус</span></li>`

Comment: @aepot Спасибо за такой подробный ответ. Разобрался и все работает как надо!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @aepot А чем отличается HttpClient client = new HttpClient();который вы использовали? Я до этого использовал HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb(); с HtmlDocument document = web.Load("https://www.litres.ru/dzhoan-ketlin-rouling/ikabog/");

Comment: @ils2 как минимум тем, что он асинхронный. Ну и как бы это современное .NET API, рекомендованное к использованию Microsoft'ами. То есть не морозит ваше приложение, пока грузит страницу. [Асинхронное программирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async). Помимо всего прочего, он переиспользует открытые соединения к серверу, это позитивно сказывется на производительности, если вы делаете много запросов к одному сайту или API (раза в 3 быстрее). И вишенка на торте - он поддерживает HTTP/2. C ходу всё объяснить не получится, но вы поизучайте обязательно, если работаете с HTTP.

Comment: @ils2 да, все что я рассказал про производительность, это больше для .NET Core/.NET 5. Если вы используете .NET Framework, то все равно, будете вы использовать `HttpClient` или `HtmlWeb`. Ну если только в асинхронности разница будет.

Comment: @aepot Это у меня для сайта который на asp.net MVC. Вот у `HtmlWeb` вроде нашел асинхронный метод `LoadFromWebAsync`, до этого у меня было только `Load`. В итоге получилось вот так `HtmlDocument document = await web.LoadFromWebAsync("https://www.litres.ru/detskie-knigi/priklucheniya/");`

Comment: @ils2 Разница тут в том, что `HtmlWeb` - это [обертка](https://github.com/zzzprojects/html-agility-pack/blob/ee9b6d9d4c384c0735a9f24316ba5ff2b0886ff5/src/HtmlAgilityPack.Shared/Metro/HtmlWeb.cs#L114) разработчиков `HtmlAgilityPack` над стандартным `HttpClient`, который дает ряд простых инструментов управления для загрузки нужного HTML документа сразу библиотекой. Через `HttpClient` вы это делаете руками и немного иначе, но и позволяет чуть больше возможностей (например кодировка).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Теперь понял. Спасибо